# Waiting for a page to load - Cypress

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, cypress, pageload

I'm having an issue as the page is not fully loaded. I tried the `cy.wait(1000)` method, which I do believe is not a good solution, but still not working, the page is not fully loaded.

Here is the website that I'm trying to test `https://www.24mx.ie/`. The
code is in the file `homePage.js`.

```
class HomePage {
  static loadHomePage() {
    cy.visit(Cypress.env('url') + '.ie/');
    cy.wait(1000)      
  }

  static acceptCookies() {
    cy.get('div.m-button.m-button--navigation.m-button--xs.qa-consent-agree-btn.ng-tns-c95-8').click();
  }
}

export default HomePage
```

code in the file homePage.spec.js

```
import HomePage from '../pageObjects/homePage'

describe('Home Page Test', function () {
    it('Home Page TC', function () {
        HomePage.loadHomePage();
    })

    it('Accepting Cookies TC', function () {
        HomePage.acceptCookies();
    })

})
```

Here is a print screen from the test:

[image]

Comment: So, where does the test fail? If `.acceptCookies()` succeeds, you should continue the test by asserting one of the products. It may be that Cypress just stops updating the screen once tests are done (as @Mikkel says).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To make sure the page has loaded successfully, you can assert any element to be visible. Since after page load you're clicking the accept cookie button I would suggest to assert the same as visible, something like:

```
class HomePage {
  static loadHomePage() {
    cy.visit(Cypress.env('url') + '.ie/');
    cy.get('[class*=qa-consent-agree-btn]', {
      timeout: 5000
    }).should('be.visible') //Make sure Cookie Accept button is visible with timeout of 5 seconds. You can increase timeout as required.     
    }

    static acceptCookies() {
      cy.get('[class*=qa-consent-agree-btn]').click();
    }
  }

  export default HomePage
```

Comment: Thanks, still the page in not fully loaded.

Comment: @Eni What does this return - `Cypress.env('url')`

Comment: Can you change that to `https://www.24mx`. Then I think it should work.

Comment: still not working.
{
    "chromeWebSecurity": false,
    "reporter": "mochawesome",
    "projectId": "Eni2021",

    "env": 
    {
        "url": "https://www.24mx"
    }
}

Comment: the url it is as you mentioned above.

Comment: what is your cypress version?

Comment: it has version v6.5.0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229624/discussion-between-alapan-das-and-eni).

Answer (score 16):

You should just do a `cy.get()` and `.should()` to make Cypress wait for something to appear on the page.

If the page is busy doing API requests, you can do a `cy.intercept()` on one or more of the API calls, and wait for them. This will buy you some time before you wait for an element to appear. You can look at the network tab in the Chrome debug tools to see what API requests the page is making. I would pick one that takes some time to load, and wait for that.

This is a much better way of "waiting" for the page to load than doing a `cy.wait()`

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer. Better than using cy.wait()