# Cypress - how to wait for first time page to load

Tags: node.js, cypress

I'm trying to run a cypress (v8.7.0) test where my application takes very long to render the page on the first page load. When I call `cy.visit()`, I get an error saying failed trying to load `ESOCKETTIMEDOUT`. I tried some of the suggestions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68975353/4896260), such as:

```
cy.visit('https://github.com/', { timeout: 30000 })
```

and in `cypress.json`

```
{
  ...
  "pageLoadTimeout": 120000
}
```

However, it still fails. How can I go about this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a better solution. The issue is that cypress is running a process which starts the server, at takes long on the initial visit. I've done the following work around. The `cy.request` fails, but when I set the retry option, it works. After a successful call, it can call the `cy.visit` without that issue.

```
cy.request({
  url:'http://localhost:3000/myUrl',
  timeout: 120000,
  retryOnStatusCodeFailure: true
}).visit('http://localhost:3000/myUrl');
```

Answer (score 0):

To make sure the page has loaded successfully, you can assert any element to be visible.

**Check this answer** https://stackoverflow.com/a/66517138/14517464

Comment: In this case, I can't assert any element as the the error occurs in the `cy.visit()` command. It never finishes executing, but throws the timeout out instead.